# My question is about mongodb do a query between multiple collection in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to use mongodb to do a query link SQL join table in PHP

Two collection are like following

Courses:

{
    "CourseID": "CS101",
    "Title": "Introduction to Data Science",
    "Level": 6
  },

{
    "CourseID": "CS102",
    "Title": "Application Design and Development",
    "Level": 6
  },

Offer:

{
    "DeptID": "CS",
    "CourseID": "CS101",
    "Year": 2016,
    "ClassSize": 40,
    "AvailablePlaces": 40
  },

I'm trying to make the result like the following:
[prefering result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myi1V.png)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is not a relational database, but you can perform a left outer join by using the $lookup stage.

The **$lookup** stage lets you specify which collection you want to join with the current collection, and which fields that should match. Here's the [official doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

```
dbo.collection('courses').aggregate([
    { $lookup:
       {
         from: 'offer',
         localField: 'CourseID',
         foreignField: 'CourseID',
         as: 'availableplaces'
       }
     }
    ])
```